# Bootstrap accordion arrow color

Tags: bootstrap-5

How can I change the color of the *collapsed* accordion arrow? I've tried more solutions but I managed to change only the button's text color.

The constant color is a blue which isn't compatible with dark background at all.

Example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override the .accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after

```css
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%230c63e4'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
```

by:

```css
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after {
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23YOUR_HEX_CODE'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
        }
```

Replace "YOUR_HEX_CODE" by your hex code without # in the previous instruction

Comment: Well done figuring that one out.

Comment: Nice. In my case I also had to add `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

The active color of the arrow is determined by the SCSS variable `$accordion-icon-active-color` as can be seen in their [source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/da0fe8c8b2e969bcf620a9ef1c1ca4f2b8554ec6/scss/_variables.scss#L1282).

You can overwrite it by doing the following in your global scss file:

```
$accordion-icon-active-color: #ffffff; // your new color code
@import "bootstrap/variables";
```